# How to use isset to show new data after submit and POST page refresh?

Tags: php

I use the following to POST a new file and works fine:

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="file" name="postImage" multiple="multiple" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <input id="uploadImg" name="uploadImgCustom" type="submit" value="AGGIORNA ALLEGATO" class="btn secondary-btn primary-bg">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPLOAD LOGIC**

```
$myNewImg = get_post_meta($id, 'usp-file-single', true);
if (isset($_POST['uploadImgCustom'])) {
    $myNewImg = $_POST['uploadImgCustom'];
}
$attachments = get_posts(array( 
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_status' =>'any',
    'post_parent' => $id
));

if ($attachments) {
    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
        $myNewImg = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID );
        update_post_meta( $id, 'usp-file-single', $myNewImg);
    } 
    $pathtofile = $myNewImg;
    $info = pathinfo($pathtofile);
    if ( ($info["extension"] == "jpg") || ($info["extension"] == "png") ) { ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $myNewImg; ?>" class="bnr_img img-responsive center-block" alt="">
        </a>
    <?php } else { 
        // Get the Video Fields
        $video_mp4 =  get_post_meta($id, 'usp-file-single', TRUE);
        // Build the  Shortcode
        $attr =  array(
            'mp4'      => $video_mp4,
            'webm'     => $video_webm,
            'flv'      => $video_flv,
            'poster'   => $video_poster,
            'preload'  => 'auto',
            'autoplay' => "off"
        );
        // Display the Shortcode
        echo wp_video_shortcode(  $attr );
    } 
}
```

**POST CHECK**

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST") {
  if ('AGGIORNA ALLEGATO' === ($_POST['uploadImgCustom'])) {
    if ($_FILES['postImage']) {
        $attachments = get_attached_media( '', $id );
        foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
            wp_delete_attachment( $attachment->ID, 'true' );
        }   
        foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
            if ($_FILES[$file]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
           //Add your error action
            } else {    
                $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file, $id );
                $myNewImg = get_post_meta($id, 'usp-file-single', true);
            }
        }   
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to place the following before the html form

```
$myNewImg = get_post_meta($id, 'usp-file-single', true);
if (isset($_POST['uploadImgCustom'])) {
    $myNewImg = $_POST['uploadImgCustom'];
}
```

However the page refreshes after the POST but I see the old value, if I manually refresh after the post refresh, I can see the new value tho. Am I using wrongly `if isset`?

Comment: you mean you want to retain the last uploaded file after submission in the input file? isn't that a security issue if its possible

Comment: @Ghost nope, I am sending a file to DB, this changes what's in the db, it basically replaces it and works fine. however I am displaying this file on the page, but when I submit, the page shows the old one, yet the new file is in the db and I need to manually refresh the page again. It looks like cache of the page or something

Comment: i don't know how the markup and the code are constructed in succession, but you could just follow the post redirect get pattern so that you get the new one

Comment: the html mark up is what you see in there @Ghost you mean use GET instead of POST right? What about security?

Comment: no, what i mean is, submit (the form being submitted) -> redirect -> fetch image. to elaborate, get the submitted image, upload it and whatnot and save the meta data and everything which you already have, redirect to the page where new image resides, then fetch as usual, which you also already have, just add a redirection in between after form submission

Comment: @Ghost I thought to add my own redirection, it's a trick but I guess it'll work since it works if I manually redirect, based on the code on the question where would you put it tho?

Comment: you could simply add the redirection after all of the files are submitted. you could add it after the foreach block line

Comment: @Ghost thanks a lot, worked. Pasted my own answer based on your suggestion tho, let me know if you want to paste your answer I'll delete mine and accept yours

Comment: no need to, self answer will suffice. just provide the answer on how you solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to a suggestion in comment, I eventually created a page refresh like this:

```
<?php
    $myNewUploaded = get_post_meta($id, 'usp-file-single', true);
    if (isset($_POST['uploadImgCustom'])) {
        $myNewImg = $_POST['postImage'];
        ob_start(); //this should be first line of your page
        $myurl = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
        header('Location: '.$myurl);
        ob_end_flush(); //this should be last line of your page
    }
?>
<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">.....
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
   $myNewImg = get_post_meta($id, 'usp-file-single', true);
    if (!isset($_POST['uploadImgCustom'])) {
    $myNewImg = $_POST['uploadImgCustom'];
    }
```

Comment: nope, I tried putting before the form and after the form, still see either the old file or an empty place right after submission, yet the file is uploaded and if I refresh i see it

Comment: have you used this `!isset()` and try to place before the submission ?

Comment: yes I have copied your code and if I place ti before the html form, the file is submitted and saved but once the page refreshes I don't see it. if I then manually refresh again then I can see the new file

Comment: so what you basically want to do with the file please clear us your question

Comment: in php u have to get back the submitted image, if you had used ajax then it would be really easy